# Webpack.config.js not being loaded in new rails 6 app

Tags: jquery, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I have set-up a new Rails 6 app to work with tailwindcss and it's the first time I've experienced using webpack properly. I'm trying to use jquery and want to ensure that any reference of $ or jquery in my scripts are support properly

I've [followed the instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-jquery-ui) for installing the jquery-ui package which required me to create a webpack.config.js file, but it doesn't seem to work unless I also define the jquery tags in application.js.

Whilst this solves my issue temporarily, I want to ensure webpack.config.js is set up correctly up for future use.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index:'./src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundled.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath:'dist/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader","css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
        loader:"file-loader",
        options:{
          name:'[name].[ext]',
          outputPath:'assets/images/'
          //the images will be emited to dist/assets/images/ folder
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    /* Use the ProvidePlugin constructor to inject jquery implicit globals */
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery'",
        "window.$": "jquery"
    })
  ]
};
```

**application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require('webpack-jquery-ui');

import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "www",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "webpack-jquery-ui": "^2.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.0.3",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using node modules to install the jquery then the path 'jquery/src/jquery' indicates the jquery installed in node_modules directory having sub directory 'jquery/src'and which contains jquery.js file there.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
})
```

i solved my issue using this. Hope this will be helpful.

Reference: https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/introducing-jquery-in-rails-6-using-webpacker[enter link description here](https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/introducing-jquery-in-rails-6-using-webpacker)